# First preparedStatement using Cassandra always slow

Tags: cassandra

I noticed if I have a java method in which I have a preparedStatement uisng the JDBC driver that comes with Cassandra it is always slow. But if I put the same query twice in the method the second time it is 20x faster. Why is that? I would think the second, third, four time I call the java method it would be faster then the first. I am using Cassandra 1.2.5. I have also cached 100MB of rows in the row-cache and set the table to caching = "all". In Cassandra-cli I verified the settings. And in Cassandra-Cli I verified the second, third fourth time I get the rows from the same table I do the JDBC calls against I get faster response time.
Any Ideas?

Thanks,
-Tony

Answer (score 0):

From the all knowing [CQL3 documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html) (always a great starting point btw):

> Prepared statement is an optimization that allows to parse a query only once but execute it multiple times with different concrete values.

The  statement gets cached. This is the difference maker you are experiencing. Also prepared statements get pre-compiled, typically meaning an execution plan is prepared before the query is run against the db. Knowing what you are doing makes the process faster.

At the first run your prepared statement is cached in-case you run the same query again, which you do, and since its cached the querying will be executed much faster.